# postgis- how to apply st_buffer

Tags: postgis

I have imported a line shapefile in pgadmin and would like to apply a buffer of 3m on all line segments

I've read the st_buffer specification but cannot figure out what to type in as a geometry to expand, column names don't seem to work

any help would be appreciated

screenshot of table (partial but I hope t helps):

[image: 1]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Please add 1) create table and insert statements with data sample 2) what you've tried so far and 3) the exact expected result. Otherwise it is highly unlikely that anyone will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have the one `geometry` type column named `geom`. If you want to replace the lines in there, run an `update`:

```sql
update table your_table set geom=st_buffer(geom,3);
```

If you want to keep the original shapes and add their buffer shapes separately, add a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```sql
alter table your_table add column geom_buffer_3 geometry 
    generated always as (ST_Buffer(geom,3)) stored;
```

It always generate the buffer shape automatically whenever you insert new data into that table, or update the existing rows.

Keep in mind the unit of distance depends on the column SRID - if you're using metric you'll get anomalies from systems in imperial/nautical/degrees. If your data is in degrees like in [SRID 4326](https://epsg.io/4326), `ST_Buffer(geom,3)` will be a buffer 3 geographic degrees big, which is 333 kilometers on the equator.

Comment: pedantic note: `ST_Buffer(geom,3)` cannot be automatic translated to a 3 metres buffer, as it depends on the geometry's SRS. For instance it would mean 3 degrees if the geometry is encoded as WGS84.

Comment: @JimJones Good idea to point that out in a thread like this. Added.